# Unable to send data to database while using MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am using react js and Mongodb for web development. My aim is to create a team UI which can store the team name in the team database. I have two portion of the project client side where I created the UI designs and server-side where I created the database schema and backend connection to send the data to the database.

The team schema: The name of the file is TeamName.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    team_name: String
    
});

const Team = mongoose.model("Team", TeamSchema);

module.exports = Team;
```

The connection code which is in the server-side index.js page

```
const Team = require('./schema/TeamName.js'); const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoString ="connection string"
mongoose.connect(mongoString)
const database = mongoose.connection
database.on('error', (error) => console.log(error))
database.once('connected', () => console.log('Database Connected'))
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors()) app.post('/createTeam', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const team = new Team(req.body);
        console.log(team);
        await team.save();
        res.send(team);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})  app.get('/getTeam', async (req, res) =>{
    const team = await Team.find()
    res.json(team);
})
```

The front End design for the teampage is

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Team({ setActive }) {
  const [teamValues, setTeamValues] = useState({
    team_name: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTeamValues({ ...teamValues, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    / Post teamValues data to your server endpoint
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/createTeam', teamValues)
      .then((res) => {
        // Handle successful team creation, e.g., redirect to team list page
        setActive('Login');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('Error in creating the team');
      });



return (
<div className="container mt-5">
  <div className="row justify-content-center">
    <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
            <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h2 className="card-title">Create a New Team</h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Team Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="team_name"
                value={teamValues.team_name}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
              Create Team
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
       );
      }
```

The screenshot of the form

[image]

The aim of the UI design is if I provide a team name on the form it will be stored on the database. I was unable to store it. However, I can find a table on the Monogodb database, named Team. I tried to use this UI to store a team name. Then I checked the database the teamname was not stored. One instance was created which only has team id. This team id is system-generated.

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong in my UI design?

Comment: You need to debug it and learn how to narrow down what causes the issue. I see you already did `console.log(team)`. Did it return anything interesting? it is a demarcation point. if the name is there, it confirms the clientside, delivery, and models are good, and you need to focus on mongoose / mongodb. Otherwise check what's been sent from the browser, e.g. with `console.log(req.body)`. Usually by the time when you isolate the problem to the level of SO recommendations the answer will be obvious =)

Comment: There is no error message on the code but it unable to store the team name.

Comment: What is the output of `req.body` ?

Comment: I figured it out. I messed up with variable names.

Comment: well done! you see - a little bit of effort and the missing underscore becomes obvious.