# Unable to show the content of the form in the UI page

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am using React JS and MongoDB to create teamlist. So far I am able to submit the name of the "Team" in the database. The code for this portion is [Submitting team name in the MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196110/unable-to-send-data-to-database-while-using-mongodb)

My next goal is to show the list of the team names in the same UI page which I use as a form for submitting the team name in the database.

For that, I created a new javascript page named "Teamlist.js". The code for this page is

```
import React from 'react';

function TeamList({ teams }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Team List</h3>
      <ul>
        {teams.map((team) => (
          <li key={team._id}>{team.team_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TeamList;
```

Then I modified my Team.js page (UI page - link above) like that

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import TeamList from './TeamList'; // Import the TeamList component

export default function Team({ setActive }) {
  const [teamValues, setTeamValues] = useState({
    team_name: '',
  });

  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]); // Initialize as an empty array

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the list of teams from your server
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:9000/getTeams') // Replace with your endpoint
      .then((response) => {
        setTeams(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTeamValues({ ...teamValues, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Post teamValues data to your server endpoint
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:9000/createTeam', teamValues)
      .then((res) => {
        // Handle successful team creation, e.g., redirect to team list page
        if (res.data) {
          alert('Team creation Successful');
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('Error in creating the team');
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Create a New Team</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Team Name:</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="team_name"
                    value={teamValues.team_name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                  Create Team
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className="mt-3 text-center">
            <a href="/TeamRoster" className="Team_Roster">
              create a team roster
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Display the list of teams */}
      <TeamList teams={teams} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got error an error that "Error in creating the team". I did not understand what was wrong with my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any console logs in the backend or even console log the err.message in the frontend

Comment: No, Only error message is "Error in creating the team". The way I implemented the code to show the all team names is it correct?

Comment: can you do a console log on the createteam endpoint in the bbackend to see what the error is. also instead of writing a custom message in the alert u can put the err.message just for debugging purposes

Comment: I changed the backend "app.post('/createTeam', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const team = new Team(req.body);
        console.log(team);
        await team.save();
        res.send(team);
    } catch (error) {
        //res.status(500).send(error);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
})" - Now there is no error message the team created successfully but I can not see the team list on the same page. I can see only a heading like Team List but the values or the name of the teams are missing. How can I solve this part?

Comment: `.catch((err) => {
        alert('Error in creating the team');
      }` shallows the error. You should add a `console.error(err)` inside the catch to have the opportunity to get the error. You should also take a look into the network tab of the developer tool. You should see the HTTP request, and maybe details in the body of the response.

Comment: It's working now